# Pass_fds alternative in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, popen

I am currently using popen to call a Unix command which accepts multiple files as arguments and instead of using files I would like to pass the data from memory as a variable/file object. With this command actual files need to be specified with the command as it does not read them from STDIN. I can pass one file to the command by using '/dev/fd/0' as an argument and passing the contents of the file to STDIN, via communicate() but I am looking for a way to pass multiple files.

I believe I need to use file descriptors here in order to achieve this and from looking I can see python 3+ has an option called pass_fds, but no such option exists in 2.7.

Is there any way to do this in python 2.7, I guess you'd need to use os.pipe perhaps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there's a much better way of doing but I managed to do what I needed:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
import os

fakefiles = []
fd2 = 10 # Arbitrary starting fd number
fakefiles.append("""The entire
content of
file one
""")
fakefiles.append("content of file two")

def fd_file_list(fd, maxrange):
    fdlist = []
    for i in range(0, maxrange):
        fdlist.append('/dev/fd/' + str(fd)) 
        fd += 1
    return fdlist

def create_fds(fd, files):
    for content in files:
        r, w = os.pipe()
        w = os.fdopen(w, 'w')
        w.write(content)
        w.close() 
        os.dup2(r, fd)
        fd += 1

fd_files = fd_file_list(fd2, len(fakefiles))
p2 = Popen(['/home/pi/myscript.sh'] + fd_files, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, preexec_fn=create_fds(fd2, fakefiles))
out, err = p2.communicate()
print out
```

Where the content of /home/pi/myscript.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash

((!$#)) && exit 

for i; do
  echo -e "\n\nfile is $i"
  cat $i
done
```